# Bulk editing HTML on multiple pages?

Tags: html

For example, if I'm building a page header with a menu that will appear on every single page of a website, if and when I want to make changes to the menu on every page, is there a way to implement this change on every page without having to edit every single HTML page?

Let's say my menu has 5 tabs and at a later date I want to add a 6th tab, or remove a tab, is there an efficient way of doing this without having to manually edit the HTML on every single page?

Comment: you can.t do it with html only.YOu can use angular for front end and if using php for html coding also then go with require() or include()

Answer (score 1):

HTML *itself* doesn't provide such a mechanism, though SGML, the language in which the HTML element vocabulary is/was originally specified, *does* in the form of [entities/entity references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182776/duplicate-some-parts-of-xml-without-rewriting-them/50183845#50183845). Using SGML entities, you'd typically create an SGML file containing just your menu, and then pull-in that file from multiple individual page content files:

```
<!-- content of menu.sgml file -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <!-- ... further menu items -->
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- content of page.sgml pulling-in menu.sgml -->
<!DOCTYPE html [
  <!-- this declares the "menu" entity -->
  <!ENTITY menu SYSTEM "menu.sgml">
]>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Menu demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- this pulls-in menu.sgml as if it were part
         of page.sgml directly --> 
    &menu
    <main>
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Main content of your page</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now you'd only edit `menu.sgml` and have your updated menu content always up-to-date in any page files referencing `menu.sgml`. You can even leave out the declaration for `menu` (and the whole `DOCTYPE` document prolog) since SGML resolves the `&menu` entity reference to a file of that name in the same directory as the referencing file by default.

**Note**: browsers don't implement SGML. To make use of SGML in browsers (and/or on the server side as well when using node.js), you can use my sgmljs.net SGML parser/lib; see http://sgmljs.net/docs/sgmlrefman.html#general-entities for discussion of relevant entity techniques.

Commonly used server-side template libs such as Jade, pug, handlebars, mustache, etc. all have their own mechanisms called *partials* or *includes* to get functionality more or less equivalent to SGML general entities.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is also using PHP you could add it with the help of the include statement there.

Otherwise here is a JavaScript solution:

menu.html

```
<a href="a.html">Start</a><br>
<a href="b.html">Page 2</a><br>
<a href="c.html">Page 3</a><br>
```

script.js

```
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Your "normal" files

```
<div w3-include-html="menu.html"></div> <!-- put that line where you want to include the HTML. -->

<script>
includeHTML();
</script> <!-- Put that at the end of your file. -->
```

From here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp